# How to implement the Permission API on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, user-permissions

I am using dialogFlow to get user's details (name, location, Number). I then send this details to an email. I have two intents: one asks the user if they got assisted if not the second intent gets triggered, the second intent is the one responsible to take customer's details.

How can I implement the Permission API in order for Google to publish my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the permission constructor to ask permission with agents in the current context.

In the intent Map

```
intentMap.set("LocationIntent - yes", senderLocationYes);
intentMap.set("LocationIntent - yes", senderLocationAccess);


function senderLocationYes(agent) {
    const conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(
        new Permission({
            context: "To use your location for tracking purpose",
            permissions: "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
        })
    );
    agent.add(conv);
}

function senderLocationAccess(agent) {
    const conv = agent.conv();
    const location = conv.device.location;
    console.log(location);// here is the location
    conv.ask('Great ! I will need few more details. Plese help me with that.');
    conv.ask('What is your good name ?');
    agent.add(conv);
}
```

Please make sure to configure this intent in your intent map and as well as dialog flow.